# Rails posting form data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I was looking at some tutorials on rails and found that people use a separate create function for saving form data. When i tried the same i was unable to repopulate the form, that is shown in the index.html.erb and is rendered by the index function. should i add a manual render command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set a member variable (e.g.) @elems to contain data
2. In your view index.html.erb test for emptiness
3. If not empty, populate form elements with @elems .

Comment: that isn't too DRY... is it??? currently i am doing using if request.post? in the same action... that seems to be more DRY to me...

Comment: instance variables like this one are meant to be shared between the controller and the view.